# Добавление текста в фото при помощи tkinter, pillow

Tags: python, tkinter, pillow

Всем привет[image: введите сюда описание изображения]! Хочу реализовать программу, которая будет добавлять в фото текст из поля ввода "Entry" при нажатие кнопки, как показано на картинки. Не могу понять как это реализовать, помогите в решение вопроса

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas
from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Button, Entry
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.grid()

image = Image.open("image2.jpg")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

entr = Entry().grid(row= 1, column=1)

btn = Button(frame, text="Кнопка").grid(row=1, column=2)

canvas = Canvas(root, height=600, width=600)
img = canvas.create_image(300, 300, image=photo)
canvas.create_text(?)
canvas.grid(row=2, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сначала делаете функцию, которая будет срабатывать при нажатии кнопки. Внутри этой функции пррописываете код для получения текста из виджета Entry и в этой же функции прописываете код для создания текста на канвасе. Затем связываете функцию и кнопку (при создании кнопки прописываете `command = function_name`)

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas
from tkinter.ttk import Frame, Button, Entry
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


def draw_text(): # функция
    text = entr.get() # получаем текст из entr
    canvas.create_text(300, 300, text=text, fill="white", font='Arial 15 bold')
# 300, 300 - координаты x,y для текста, fill - цвет текста, font - шрифт


root = Tk()
frame = Frame(root)
frame.grid()

image = Image.open("image2.jpg")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

entr = Entry()
entr.grid(row= 1, column=1) # нужно разнести в 2 строки, 
# чтобы можно было использовать get() для получения текста

btn = Button(frame, text="Кнопка", command=draw_text).grid(row=1, column=2)

canvas = Canvas(root, height=600, width=600)
img = canvas.create_image(300, 300, image=photo)

canvas.grid(row=2, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Спасибо заработало. Еще вопрос, как новую картинку с текстом сохранить в формате jpg? я так понимаю canvas в формате ps сохранит.

Comment: Вы можете конвертировать из ps в jpg с помощью модуля PIL. ```from PIL import Image img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(ps.encode('utf-8'))) img.save(r'C:\Users\user1\Desktop\new_image.jpg')```